# Cannot assign this. variables in object prototypes

Tags: javascript, oop, this, prototype, encapsulation

I'm currently studying javascript prototypes and I'm quite confused on how it really works. I have this code snippet and it works perfectly

```
function Message(msg){
    this.msg =msg;
}

Message.prototype = {

    constructor:Message,
    display: function(){
         return this.msg;
    }

};


alert(new Message("007").display());
```

What this code is trying to do is to illustrate a simple encapsulation by using javascript.

Now the problem is, I want to add this **text:this.msg** instead of using the display method

```
Message.prototype = {

    constructor:Message,
    someValue:99,
    text: this.msg,
    display: function(){
         return this.msg;
    }

};
```

But i only get undefined when i call

```
 alert(new Message("007").text);
```

But calling

```
alert(new Message("007").someValue);
```

Displays 99. What is the problem here?

Comment: That is because while  preparing `Message.prototype` object, `this` does not refer to the `Message` class.

Comment: If you want some *shared property* on your prototype object access properties (like `.msg`) of individual instances, you need a getter!

Comment: @Bergi getter from the original object or in prototype?

Comment: @ReubenJaMesAveñoGruta I mean  `get text() { return this.msg }` in the prototype. Accessing `.text` on an instance will have that instance as `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time the prototype is being declared, it sees the line `text: this.msg,` and assigns its `text` property to the value of its `this`'s `msg` property. But the `this` at that point refers to the global/window object - whose `.msg` property is undefined.

On the other hand, when `display` is called, the instantiated object has had its constructor run, so the `msg` property of the instantiated object *has* been populated, *and* `display` is run with the expected calling context. (where `this` is the instantiated object) Just keep using the `display` property.

(Also, you don't define the constructor in the prototype: just leave off the `constructor:` line entirely in the prototype)

Comment: Thanks!  "But the 'this' at that point refers to the global/window object - whose .msg property is undefined." Does that mean a constructor or function is necessary in order to shadow the global/window object?

Comment: @Reuben JaMes Aveño Gruta you should never use `this` to refer to the global object - in fact, it's forbidden in strict mode, which is good to use. Generally, if you wanted to access a property that was on the global object, you could just use the property name, such as `foo`, to access `window.foo`.